# Sending file(s) to my PHP script via C#

Tags: c#, php, file, file-upload

I have been working on my first C# application lately and I finished working on the interface - it's perfect.

Now I am stuck at the part where I get an **Open File dialog** and then send that file to my PHP script located on **localhost** (wamp).

This is what I've been trying to do:

```
        private void menu_upload_file_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dialogOpened = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (dialogOpened == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.UploadFile("http://dugi/imgitv3/upload.php?submit=true&action=upload", "POST", filename);
                }
            }
        }
```

Nothing is happening and the file is not being sent (copied over) to my desired location.

You might understand that I am succeeding on opening the **Open File dialog**, but I have no clue if I am catching the filename/directory and send it over to my website so it can deal with it.

Maybe the url is complicated? I need to send those submit and action parameters or the script wont load.

**OH AND:** In PHP, the `$_FILES` array **MUST BE** named `images` (`$_FILES['images']`), maybe this is the problem? (thought of this while asking here).

So what is the problem that the file is not being sent to my website?

Comment: Do you have a try..catch somewhere that is swallowing the exception being raised when WebClient.UploadFile fails (assuming that is the issue)?

Comment: No, I do not, because I have no idea where to apply the try-catch and what Exception it might throw. Maybe you can help out here?

Comment: Have you tried using WireShark to see if the file gets transferred across the web? Have you looked at the logs on the "dugi" server? You said your WAMP is in localhost. Do you need to upload to LOCALHOST instead of http DUGI?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in debug mode and following the code step by step to see where it fails?

Comment: @mbeckish I just did and I can't see where it's failing. I get the response below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my PHP script. I was always looking for `$_FILES['images']` there and nothing else. Then after some googles, I noticed that C# sends the file array named with `file` (`$_FILES['file']`).

I did the necessary changes in my PHP script and now everything is working.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `client.UploadFile("http://dugi/imgitv3/upload.php?submit=true&action=upload", "POST", filename);` is not throwing an exception try to look at the response.

```
var response = client.UploadFile("http://dugi/imgitv3/upload.php?submit=true&action=upload",  "POST", filename);

Console.WriteLine("\nResponse Received.The contents of the file uploaded are:\n{0}",
                System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response));
```

Comment: no idea why, but this doesn't seem to open a command line window for me.

Comment: I tried with debugging (first time I used it) and I get this response `+  response {byte[935]} byte[]`

Comment: You have to open the `Output` window (under the `View` menu) to see the result in a GUI application.

Comment: Are you going to help me out on this @hegearon?